# Add batch-file to "Open with" dialog in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, batch

I want to open a .xyz-file from time to time with a self-written batch-Script under windows 10. For that I want to right-click the file and have the batch-Script in the "open with" dialog. How do I do this?

I can associate the batch-Script as the "default app" to open, but that is not what I want to do.

I tried with

```
assoc .xyz 
ftype xyzfiletype=C:\Program Files\batch-script.bat "%1"
```

but in the end with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method. Illustrates how to ensure your application appears in the Open With menu and dialog box for desktop apps, and is available as a default Windows Store app for specified file types.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-include-an-application-on-the-open-with-dialog-box